# odoo14 on change only gets called on specific change

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

This is the on change function of one of my models in my odoo14 module:

```py
@api.onchange('staende', 'name', 'length', 'height')
def change(self):
    print("\033[92m +++ DEBUG#ONCHANGE +++")
    print(self)
    print("\033[93m", end="")
```

weirdly enough, the method only gets called when I change the name of the model but not when I change the length or height nor the staende attribute

this is what the model looks like:

```py
class Halle(models.Model):
    _name = 'rectanglemaps.halle'
    _inherit = 'mail.thread'
    _description = 'desc'

    active = fields.Boolean('Active', default=True)

    name = fields.Char(string="Name", required=True)
    length = fields.Float(string="Länge", required=True)
    height = fields.Float(string="Tiefe", required=True)
    measurehalle = fields.Float(string="Rastermaß")
    plan = fields.Image(string="Plan")

    messe_id = fields.Many2one('rectanglemaps.messe', string="Messe")

    staende = fields.One2many('rectanglemaps.stand', 'halle_id', string="Stände")
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears, it was only a problem with hot module reloading. Restarting odoo with the flag -u MODULENAME solved the problem.